# Can secondary index help at SELECTION with INNER JOIN?

Tags: abap, opensql

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT VEKP~EXIDV VEKP~VENUM VEKP~LGNUM
       VEKP~PKTYP VEKP~PKPLA VEKP~PKBER
       VEKP~DATAB VEKP~TIMAB VEKP~DATBI VEKP~TIMBI
       VEKP~BTVOL VEKP~NTVOL VEKP~VOLEH_MAX
       VEKP~TAVOL VEKP~VOLEH
       VEKP~BRGEW VEKP~NTGEW VEKP~GEWEI_MAX
       VEKP~TARAG VEKP~GEWEI
       VEKP~VEGR1 VEKP~VEGR2 VEKP~VEGR3 VEKP~VEGR4
       VEKP~ARBZEIT VEKP~UNITARBZEIT
       VEKP~PACKERID VEKP~PACKERID2 VEKP~PACKERID3
       VEKP~PACKERID4 VEKP~PACKERID5
       VEKP~PACKVORSCHR VEKP~VHILM
       VEPO~WERKS VEPO~MATNR VEPO~VELIN VEPO~UNVEL
  FROM VEKP INNER JOIN VEPO
    ON VEKP~VENUM = VEPO~VENUM
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE LT_HU_CLASSICAL
 WHERE ( VEKP~PKBER IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-PKBER
   AND VEKP~DATBI IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-DATBI
   AND VEKP~PKPLA IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-PKPLA
   AND VEKP~TIMBI IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-TIMBI
   AND VEPO~WERKS IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-WERKS
   AND VEPO~MATNR IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-MATNR
   AND VEPO~VELIN = '1'
   AND VEKP~EXIDV IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-EXIDV )
   OR
   (  VEKP~PKBER IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-PKBER
  AND VEKP~DATBI IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-DATBI
  AND VEPO~VELIN NOT IN ('1','2')
  AND VEKP~EXIDV IN IS_SELECT_OPTIONS-EXIDV )
ORDER BY VEKP~EXIDV.
```

Based on debugging, only the select options for VEPO-WERKS, VEKP-DATBI and VEKP-PKBER contain data. DATBI uses a single value, with EQ.

This statement is way to slow and my question is:

If I create a secondary index for VEKP (with the selected fields) and another secondary index for VEPO (with the selected fields), will this increase the performance of the select statement ?

Or should I try something else ?

Comment: Why don't you try it by yourself and see? Remember however if the table you want to create secondary index on is a table with data that changes or increases frequently then it might be a challenge for the database to update such an index.

Comment: I do not have relevant test data in the quality system, so I did not want to try out directly in the productive system without knowing if it would help. But yes, the data in these tables changes quite often.

Comment: Databases usually calculate Execution Plans for the SQL queries, and store them, so you should get it in the production system (either at database level, or via ST04(N)), analyze it and take the appropriate action. We can't do it for you. There are dedicated forums for SQL performance issues.

Comment: Indexes exist on the database, so the exact effects of indexes mostly depend on what database you are using. Also, you have a lot of SELECT-OPTIONS in there. Are you using all of them or only specific ones? Have you checked which combinations of select options are the most common ones and which one cause the most performance issues?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Answer (score 2):

## It is impossible to provide the best index just from this information

Most of the fields in the WHERE condition are select options, so it is impossible to know what is in them, or if they are entirely empty for an indivitual query.
The OR just makes things worse.

### What you *should* do

*In the productive system* trace the slow executions with ST12 or ST05, or check ST04. In these places you will see which fields are actually used, and with what pattern.

You need to fit the index to the actual usage.

### As a stopgap

Field EXIDV is quite selective in my experienceand it is used in the ORDER BY.
Creating a new index on VEKP with fields [PKBER, DATBI, VENUM, EXIDV]<sup>1</sup> should help.

---

1) in this exact order, without MANDT

Comment: Let me know if it helped

Comment: The fields that are actually used are: 1. VEPO-WERKS,2. VEKP-DATBI and 3.VEKP-PKBER. I already have a index for VEPO containing WERKS and VENUM. Should I still include EXIDV in the VEKP index ?

Comment: I do not really understand the first question. PKBER and DATBI have only one value.

Comment: @OvidiuPocnet A select-option looks like an `IN` from the applicaton server side, but seen from the db it can be `=`, `BETWEEN`, `NOT LIKE`, etc. Where you see which fields are actually used, you should also see if they are used with `=` or not.

Comment: @OvidiuPocnet, also, I wanted to know how many different values are in fields PKBER and DATBI _on the db_. Hopefully not one.

Comment: I have provided the data from the debugger for DATBI: SIGN: I ; OPTION: EQ ; LOW: 20190616 ; HIGH: 00000000. In the transaction, the user has the both 'intervals' and 'extension' options enabled , but gives data only in the -LOW field.

Comment: @OvidiuPocnet, in this case EXIDV should be in the last position, it is still used by the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195202/discussion-between-andras-and-ovidiu-pocnet).